# penetration testing career path

Tags: penetration-test, career

I’m a fourth year student in computer science and I want to work as a penetration tester.

I studied this courses as a self-study:

- RHCSA
- RHCE
- CCNA
- Network+
- Security+
- C#

The question now is: can I get the CEH and after graduation, work directly as a pentester? OR I should first work as a network admin or a system admin?

Comment: no amount of certifications can equal experiance

Comment: We cannot know what your city's InfoSec job market is like to know if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Get in touch with some companies that do what you want to do and see about graduate careers. They will be able to tell you what they are looking for.

Certs are great, but experience will count for more. Start doing your own research, participate in bug bounty programs and build up a 'portfolio' you can use at interview. Being on the wall of fame for $company definitely wont hurt your chances.

Go to conferences and get involved with the community. You may well find a job via people you meet at cons. In the UK, you usually find some of the bigger companies mentioning they are recruiting. Talk to the guys in the stands. The last con I went to, companies where actively looking for graduates.